# Simulink: Perform math operations with multilevel bus signals

Tags: simulink, bus, mux

I am seeking a method to sum multilevel bus signals
at the lowest level within their hierarchy
without loss of the bus signal structure.

### MWE

For example, in the MWE below,
the bus signal is summed at the lowest level automatically,
however, the bus signal is lost after passing through the Add block.

A vector signal is produced instead.

[image: MWE]

I would have preferred a method which yields:

`red + blue = purple`

or more specifically:

`red.[a b c].[1 2] + blue.[a b c].[1 2] --> purple.[a b c].[1 2]`

where

`purple.b.3 = red.b.3 + blue.b.3`

and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, the only possibility to do math with bus signals is using a MATLAB Function block. Be aware of the potentially bad performance!

To use a MATLAB Function block, first generate a matching bus object and make sure the two bus creators mergin a / b / c each are assigned to output this bus object. Doing so you will receive an error because 1 and 2 aren't valid field names, i changed them to x1 and x2.

In the next step create a MATLAB Function Block. [Set the  two inputs and one output to your previous defined bus object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/attach-bus-signals-to-matlab-function-blocks.html). Paste the following code:

```
function y = fcn(u, v)
%#codegen

y.a=innerplus(u.a,v.a);
y.b=innerplus(u.b,v.b);
y.c=innerplus(u.c,v.c);
end

function y=innerplus(u,v)
y.x1=u.x1+v.x1;
y.x2=u.x2+v.x1;
end
```

[image]

Comment: This is a helpful start. I didn't realize that the bus structures could be interpreted in the Matlab environment as structure type elements.  Your example is specific to a certain size; I'll ask how to add the structures in a separate question and provide the link below.

Comment: @kando: It is covered in the documentation (http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/attach-bus-signals-to-matlab-function-blocks.html). If anything is unclear feel free to ask a question, but I think that should explain it.