# Matlab: Sum structures

Tags: matlab, struct

I'm looking for a very simple method to sum structures
which have identical substructure hierarchies.

**Note**: This began with an attempt to [sum bus structures in Simulink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851682/simulink-perform-math-operations-with-multilevel-bus-signals).

### MWE

Assume I have 2 structures `red` and `blue`.
Each structure has subfields `a`, `b`, and `c`.
Each subfield  has subfields `x1` and `x2`.

This is drawn below:

`red. [a, b, c].[x1, x2]`
`blue.[a, b, c].[x1, x2]`

Does a function exist such that a mathematical operator
may be applied to each parallel element of `red` and `blue`?

Something along the lines of:

`purple = arrayfun( @(x,y) x+y, red, blue)`

Comment: You probably want to add a limitation to your question: Only code which supports code generation may be used. `fieldnames` would easily solve this, but it is not supported.

Comment: @Daniel If code generation is not supported, does that signify that it will not function in Simulink in (rapid) accelerator mode? If so, I definitely would like that constraint.

Comment: @Daniel I was looking at `fieldnames`.  I couldn't get it to go beyond a single level. For example: `fieldnames(red)` functioned; however, `fieldnames(red.a)` did not. Is this a simple syntax error, or would it be worth creating a separate question?

Comment: I think even running in normal mode would be blocked having incompatible code. Not sure what went wrong with your example, `fieldnames(red.a)` should be right. What error do you get?

Comment: @Daniel . I figured `fieldnames` issue out: I'm not using `red` and `blue`; I'm using `y(1)` and `y(2)`.  Needed `fieldnames(y(1).a)` rather than `fieldnames(y.a)`.  I incorrectly assumed that since `y(1)` and `y(2)` had equivalent substructures, that I could skip the index value.

Comment: what about `structun`?

Comment: @Ander: good catch, to my surprise `structfun` is supported. Anonymous functions aren't allowed, but still very useful.

Comment: I finally gave up, don't see a possibility using dynamic code. Maybe generating the code is the only possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Realizing that dynamic code which does support arbitrary structs and supports code generation is impossible (afaik), the best possibility to simplify coding is a function which generates the code:

```
function f=structm2(s)
    e=structm3(s);
    f=strcat('y.',e,'=plus(u.',e,',v.',e,');');
    f=sprintf('%s\n',f{:});
end

function e=structm3(s)
e={};
for f=fieldnames(s).'
    f=f{1};
    if isstruct(s.(f))
        e=[e,strcat([f,'.'],structm3(s.(f)))];
    else
        e{end+1}=f;
    end

end
end
```

You call `structm2` inputting a struct and it returns the code:

```
y.a.x1=plus(u.a.x1,v.a.x1);
y.a.x2=plus(u.a.x2,v.a.x2);
y.b.x1=plus(u.b.x1,v.b.x1);
y.b.x2=plus(u.b.x2,v.b.x2);
```